# Compare Values in Many Lists and Return Entire List If Specific Values Are Equal

Tags: python, csv

Working out of python.  I have a code that has two large lists composed of smaller lists--basically `list1=[[3,2,1,5][3,2,1,2].......]`, `list2=[[2,5,122,1,1][3,1,3,1,1].......]`.  I want to compare specific values of the two lists and when they are equal, return the entire row.

I have done it on a simple basis in a file that returns all equal rows (if all elements are equal):

```
for rowi in list1:
    for rowj in list2:
         if rowi==rowj:
             print rowi
```

However, this requires all of the elements of the rows to be equal.  It would be nice to do the same thing, but instead compare say element k of rowi and element h of rowj and if they are equal return all of the rowj.

My idea of a code is:

```
w=1
while w>0:
    x=list1[w][3]
    y=list2[w][6]
    if x == y:
        print row.........
```

The code above is definitely incorrect, but it might be a lead in the right direction.

The reason this is important is because one file has extra data attached--say:  x,y,z in file 1 and a,b,x,y,z,c,d in file two.

I hope this makes sense, and I appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: So why don't you do `if rowi[k] == rowj[h]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should define "equality" of two rows first:

```
def fit_together(row1, row2):
    return row1[1] == row2[0] # or something like that


# to test all combinations:
for row1 in list1:
    for row2 in list2:
        if fit_together(row1, row2):
            do_sth()

# to test all rows with the same indices in their respective lists:
for row1, row2 in zip(list1, list2):
   if fit_together(row1, row2):
       do_sth()
```

Comment: Please upvote (click on the up-arrow above the '0') any answer that helped you and accept (click the check mark below the down-arrow) the answer that solved your problem. The currency of "thank you" is reputation and that's how you increase someone's reputation. :)

Comment: It won't let me do that without a level 15 rating--is there any other way?  In addition, if I am doing this for three different variables, is there a way to do this for three?

Comment: Accepting an answer should be possible. The nested iteration above can obviously be extended for three lists. If you want to "zip" three lists you can do something like this: `map(function_of_three_variables, list1, list2, list3)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would `zip` the lists together so you have a `tuple` at each row of both lists. Then you can compare them in a list comprehension. Below, I am comparing the second element `[1]` of both lists.

```
>>> l1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
>>> l2 = [[3,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,8,9], [9,11,12]]
>>> rows = zip(l1,l2)
>>> [i for i in rows if i[0][1] == i[1][1]]
```

Output

```
[([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3]),
 ([7, 8, 9], [1, 8, 9]),
 ([10, 11, 12], [9, 11, 12])]
```

To be clear, you can swap out whatever index you'd like

```
[i for i in rows if i[0][element_from_list_1] == i[1][element_from_list_2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate:

```
for ind,row in enumerate(list1): 
    if row[3] == list2[ind][6]: 
        print row
```

This will print the row if the  3rd element of current row in `list1` is equal to 6th element of the row at the same index in `list2`

Comment: the only issue with this is the rows don't necessarily correspond (they might..., but not necessarily).  That works, but only if the rows are even.  is there a way to do this with uneven rows?

Comment: @EMoney2130, do you mean the elements in each row may not be even or the number or rows may be different?

Comment: The elements of both rows might not be even.  ideally, I am looking to match three values from each row (which i can define as three functions)--with those three values matching up, i will be able to output specific information

Answer (score 0):

```
# n1 row index of the interesting value from the first list
# n2 ... second list
[v for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v[n1] == list2[i][n2]]
```